# How to use the TableView Scroll to hide the TableView Header together with the NavigationBar?

Tags: swift, scroll, header, xcode9, navigationbar

I am using Xcode 9 | Swift 4
How to use the TableView **Scroll** to hide and show the **TableView Header** together with the NavigationBar, as in the example photo? I want to create a full screen schema for anyone reading the text to access the information and to search. Thanks in advance for your help.
[see sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSkUp.jpg)

---

[see sample animated gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwpzr.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this tutorial I was able to implement:
https://michiganlabs.com/ios/development/2016/05/31/ios-animating-uitableview-header/

Answer (score 0):

Write this Code in **ViewDidLoad()**

```
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: view.frame.origin.x, y: view.frame.origin.y , width:200, height: 100))
    label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y:284)
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    label.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.textColor = UIColor.black
    label.text = """
    O HOMEM INTERIOR
    30.03.1954 - Chicago - Illinois - E.U.A
    tradução : Go
    """
    tableview.tableHeaderView = label
```

Using this when you scroll tableview headerview will be hide.
Hope it will helps.!

Comment: I forgot to mention. I do not only want it to hide, but to appear along with the NavigationBar.

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro, sorry did not geting your point. can you explain.?

Comment: I've added an animated gif for you to understand better. I want it at any time when reading the text, when it scrolls down, it sees the navigationbar and the header. Thank you.

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro,Using this https://github.com/andreamazz/AMScrollingNavbar library. your problem view be slove.

Comment: but can you add a header together, or a view with a label to show the title of the book?

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro,yes. using my code you will able to add header of table view. in this you can customise view as per your requirement.

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro, know you can check my edited code. it's help to you.

Comment: Right! got it. I'm trying to implement. Thank you!

Comment: How to solve this? Use of unresolved identifier 'header'

Comment: replace header as view

Comment: Sorry for my lack of experience, but I've done everything to implement AMScrollingNavbar, but it just does not work. I followed the Demo. Nothing happens.

Comment: hello @OséiasRibeiro, accept this answer and ask another question for  AMScrollingNavbar. so i can add answer in to that perticular question

Comment: Sorry! Thanks :)

Comment: I've asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920782/amscrollingnavbar-does-not-work-nothing-happens