# AMScrollingNavbar does not work. Nothing happens

Tags: swift, xcode, scroll, uinavigationcontroller, installation

I'm trying to implement AMScrollingNavbar. I already installed it by the pod, no error appears. I followed all the Readme and Demo procedures. AMScrollingNavbar does not work. Nothing happens. Can anybody help me?

[Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NZ6zC.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Follow this step you will get result**

**Step1:-** after install pod  assign "ScrollingNavigationController" is class to navigation controller

**Step2:-** viewdidAppear() Method call

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
            super.viewDidAppear(animated)
            if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
                navigationController.followScrollView(tableview, delay: 0.0, followers: [NavigationBarFollower(view: view, direction: .scrollUp)])
                navigationController.scrollingNavbarDelegate = self
            }
        }
```

**Step3:-** ScrollingNavigationControllerDelegate method call

```
extension ViewController: ScrollingNavigationControllerDelegate {
    func scrollingNavigationController(_ controller: ScrollingNavigationController, willChangeState state: NavigationBarState) {
        view.needsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}
```

Hope it's Helps to you.!!

Comment: does not work. I tried everything I did what you said and nothing! import AMScrollingNavbar

class ListTextParagMsgViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { ...

Comment: override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let navigationController = self.navigationController as? ScrollingNavigationController {
            navigationController.followScrollView(mTableView, delay: 0.0, followers: [NavigationBarFollower(view: shadowView, direction: .scrollUp)])
            navigationController.scrollingNavbarDelegate = self
        }
    }

Comment: extension ListTextParagMsgViewController: ScrollingNavigationControllerDelegate {
    func scrollingNavigationController(_ controller: ScrollingNavigationController, willChangeState state: NavigationBarState) {
        view.needsUpdateConstraints()
    }
}

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro, which type of error you got. can you share your code.?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/97muhzslfl48yrf/ListTextParagMsgViewController.swift?dl=0

Comment: @OséiasRibeiro,i have share with you my file and my out put with it's working for me check link here:- https://drive.google.com/file/d/1GzqpxJRQOyHhiG-sqNh_OhS0Xo0OB2sY/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks Nishee. The big problem was this code: mSearchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
It simply made sure nothing happens. I created another project as the Class ViewController that sent me and I was comparing with my previous project until find. Now, the option I want, does not seem to exist. Make a custom view disappear and appear along with the NavigatorBar, such as Seach. Regardless of the position in the tableview the view should appear along with the NavigationBar

Comment: @Oséias Ribeiro, welcome. I'm glad it's helpful to you.can you approved my answer.thanks in advance.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything!

Answer (score 0):

- Did you import that framework inside the .swift file?
- If you're doing it in storyboard, it should appear right away (add UINavigationController and change its class
- Are you sure you're inside that VC, waiting for the result?

You might want to add your code/screens, it's hard to tell.

Comment: I add one photo of the Main.Storyboard. I am using: `import Foundation
import UIKit
import AMScrollingNavbar

class ListTextParagMsgViewController: UIViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource { .... `

Comment: Try typing the Class name again (ScrollingNavigationController), press Enter. In the storyboard you can see - it **should** inherit module from the target and change the view/right panel options right away

Comment: I did it. When I add the Class ScrollingNavigationController, in Module: AMScrollingNavbar - But nothing happens.

Comment: This Class: https://www.dropbox.com/s/97muhzslfl48yrf/ListTextParagMsgViewController.swift?dl=0

Comment: This is TableViewControler: https://www.dropbox.com/s/dqcbubw6s1318xk/screen2.jpeg?dl=0